# Tab crashes when using window MutationObserver with Angular HostBinding

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, webapi, mutation-observers

I encountered a very weird bug when adding a MutationObserver to my application.
One of my Angular components is using HostBinding to the attr.style attribute of the element, this was working fine with the mutation observer I was injecting to the page (From another js file) up until a few days ago when I set the attributes flag to true for the mutation observer, then the tab crashed completely and got stuck in a loop.
I'm not sure why, the mutation observer shouldn't cause or trigger any new events, it should only observe, so I don't see how listening to the attributes of elements in the page can cause it, unless it does something more than just listening?

I set up a quick demo, there are 2 HostBindings, the first is irrelevant to the issue, the main issue is with binding to the attr.style.
If you want to recreate the bug, set the attributes flag to true for the observer.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hostbinding-class-demo-ud5m8g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

I tried to set the attributes flag to false and it did help, I just don't understand why. I need to keep using that flag. Another option, is to remove that binding and simply set that css rule manually later.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 >This is a {{name}}!!!</h1>
  <button (click)='activate()'>Activate</button>`,
  styles: [
    `
   h1 { font-family: montserrat;}`,
  ],
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  toggle: boolean;
  toogle: boolean;

  @HostBinding('class.Current')
  get t() {
    console.log('getter-toggle function called');
    return this.toggle;
  }
  @HostBinding('attr.style')
  public get cssVariables() {
    console.log('getter-cssRules function called');
    const cssVariables = `
    --sq-color: blue
    `;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(cssVariables);
  }

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  activate() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    console.log(this.toggle);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let observer = new MutationObserver(this.logChanges);

    observer.observe(window.document.documentElement, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
      attributes: false, // Switch this to true if you want to crash the tab
    });
  }

  logChanges(records, observer) {
    for (const record of records) {
      console.log(record);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is very weird, that you're creating a mutation observer from a component that watches over document changes that include changes in the component. But maybe that's just an example code.

The `@HostBinding('attr.style')` sets new value each time the getter is called because the sanitization creates a object that is different to the previous call of the function. Therefore on each render a different value is returned.

Something in the MutationObserver listener makes the listener causes the component to re-render. That changes the style attribute and that causes the MutationObserver listener to be called again. I tried to run the listener outside the Angular Zone, but that did not help.

What helped is sanitizing the style value only once:

```
  @HostBinding('attr.style')
  public get cssVariables() {
    console.log('getter-cssRules function called');
    return this.sanitizedValue
  }

  private sanitizedValue = null

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.sanitizedValue =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`
  --sq-color: blue
  `);
  }
```

This way it works even when watching for attribute changes.

See [Stackblitz with working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hostbinding-class-demo-htt7fu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for the response.
Unfortunately for me, it's not really helpful to change the angular component itself because the product can be embedded in clients websites, so I can't make sure they won't use this binding on their application. I can either keep attributes: false for the observer or to start inspecting the client's website and check if ngZone exists for example. This is quite a big task since react also uses virtual DOM for example and I haven't tested this bug over there..